# Detect Device Make, Model, Storage and Color

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, mobile-devices

Is there any way we can detect Make, Model, Capacity and Color of mobile device in react js?. Most of the node modules which are available can only detect make and at max model. Is it possible to detect Capacity and Color as well.
**Ex- Apple iPhone 11 Pro 64GB-Black.**

Answer (score 0):

In a React.js application, we can retrieve information about the user's device using the navigator.userAgent property, but it may not provide details like device capacity or color. The navigator.userAgent property typically includes information about the browser and operating system but does not offer specific device details.

To detect more specific information such as device capacity and color, w e would need to rely on third-party APIs or services that provide device information based on the user agent. These services often use databases or algorithms to map user agents to specific device models and their associated features.